# Show that ${\lambda}x(1-x) > x$ for $1 < \lambda \leq 2$ and $x \in (0, \frac{\lambda - 1}{\lambda})$

Tags: real-analysis

The way I show that was defining $F_{\lambda} = {\lambda}x(1-x)$ and $g(x) = F_{\lambda}(x) - x$. Note that $0$ and $p_{\lambda} = \frac{\lambda - 1}{\lambda}$ are fixed points of $F_{\lambda}$. Since $g'(0) > 0$, then it is locally increasing. But if it is non-positive before $p_{\lambda}$ then, by Intermediate Value Theorem, $F_{\lambda}$ will have one more fixed point. Absurd. Therefore g is positive in $(0, p_{\lambda})$, i.e., $F_{\lambda}(x) > x$.

The point is that I believe that I'm using more things than I really need for this demonstration. Maybe I should be using some basic algebraic manipulation or the fact that $F_{\lambda}$ is strictly increasing in that interval, I don't know.

Does it have a simpler way to prove it?

Comment: Below answers are nice but one can think that why $\lambda$ has to vary as $1 < \lambda \leq 2$?, observe that if $\lambda<1$ then we have $\lambda(1-x)<1 $ as we are multiplying two smaller quantities less than 1, so yup we can think that for the inequality to hold true we must have $\lambda>1$, perhaps one can give the other bound using some graphing techiniques!

Comment: Good point! Actually it holds for any $\lambda > 1$, in fact. The graph is a parable with fixed point 0 and something lesser then 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x>0$, the required inequality is equivalent to 
$$\lambda(1-x)>1$$
which is
$$x<1-\frac1\lambda$$
which is
$$x<\frac{\lambda-1}\lambda$$
which is true.

Comment: haha I knew I was letting something very simple go by. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2):

Since $x \in (0, \frac{\lambda - 1}{\lambda})$, dividing two side of the inequality gives: $\lambda(1-x) > 1$.

Note that from the assumption:

$x < \frac{\lambda - 1}{\lambda} \quad \implies 1 - x > \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Hence: $\lambda (1 - x) > 1$ (due to $\lambda$ is positive) which is the inequality required to be proved.